# Re positioning file in CLLE

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am trying to manipulate files in CL. RCVF runs in a loop and i want to re position the file to start. I tried CLOF->OVRDBF->OPNDBF->POSDBF(*START). The subsequent RCVF is reaching end of file. Please advise on my mistake.

```
            PGM                                                  
            DCLF       FILE(LGLLISTP) OPNID(LGL)                 
            DCL        VAR(&FILENAME) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(10)        

            DSPDBR     FILE(EMPMSTP) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) +    
                         OUTFILE(QTEMP/LGLLISTP)                 

            CLOF       OPNID(LGL)                                
            OVRDBF     FILE(LGLLISTP) SHARE(*YES)                
            OPNDBF     FILE(LGLLISTP) OPTION(*INP) OPNID(LGL)    
            POSDBF     OPNID(LGL) POSITION(*START)               
READ_POS:   RCVF       OPNID(LGL)                                
            MONMSG     MSGID(CPF0864) EXEC(GOTO CMDLBL(READ_EXT))
            CHGVAR     VAR(&FILENAME) VALUE(&LGL_WHREFI)         
            GOTO       READ_POS                                  

READ_EXT:   RCVF       OPNID(LGL)                                    
            MONMSG     MSGID(CPF0864) EXEC(GOTO CMDLBL(READ_END))    
            CHGVAR     VAR(&FILENAME) VALUE(&LGL_WHREFI)             
            GOTO       READ_EXT                                      
READ_END:   CLOSE      OPNID(LGL)                                    
            ENDPGM
```

Also is it possible to do key based read and reversal read (RPGLE READP equivalent) in CL programming.

Comment: Remove CLOF, OVRDBF, OPNDBF and POSDBF commands. (It's not clear why you used those commands.) Insert CLOSE OPNID(LGL) command between the READ_EXT: label and the RCVF command. Add new label to that RCVF and change the GOTO to point to it. (The GOTOs should probably also be removed/replaced by DO-loops.) You can also remove the last CLOSE command. That should clear up the end-of-file issue as long as you're at IBM i 6.1 or later. And, yes, key-based, reverse-read is possible, but not trivial, nor should you be doing such I/O in a CL program.

Comment: @user2338816 : My intention is validate if i can reposition a file after reaching EOF in CL. To achieve that i tried using POSDBF adn OPNDBF. It doesn't to work as intended. Is it possible to reposition after reaching end of file? If there is a reference that you can point to it would be very helpful.

Comment: After reaching EOF, you can only process the file again by calling the program a second time or by use of the CLOSE command. Hmmm... I haven't tested, but it might also be possible by using _Rclose()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CL has very limited file I/O functionality...

All you can basically do is read from the start to the end.  Prior to 6.1, you couldn't restart at the beginning. With 6.1 IBM added a CLOSE command allowing you to close the file and re-start the reading from the beginning.

The following loops through a file twice.  Prior to 6.1 this was not possible.  The CLOSE command added at 6.1 makes it possible.

```
       dlcf myfile opnid(f1)

loop1: 
       rcvf opnid(f1)
       momsg cpf(CPF0864) exec(goto loop1_end)
       goto loop1
loop1_end:
      close opnid(f1)

loop2:
       rcvf opnid(f1)
       momsg cpf(CPF0864) exec(goto pgm_end)
       goto loop2
pgm_end:
       endpgm
```

If you need READP, CHAIN, ect...then use RPGLE (or C, or Java, or ...)

Comment: Thanks. This is what i was looking for. If possible could you explain me the use of OPNDBF and POSDBF.

Comment: @Sekar, they are used to prepare for I/O being done in an application (ie RPG) program.  Mostly with OPNQRYF.  Think of CL as the tool to control the environment in which an application written in RPG runs.

Comment: @Sekar Most common use possibly was for "shared" opens where the CL will call two or more application programs that process the same file. If the first program opens it as input-only and the second opens it for update, they're in conflict (as far as "sharing" goes). The CL can open the file for update before the first program runs, and that first input-only access can still work okay, while the second program's access will be fully appropriate. "Shared" opens have become less and less useful as technology makes it all so much faster.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your READ_POS: label need to be moved up a line?

also if you want to read a table backwards I suggest implementing another logical/index with records in descending order and then just read forwards

Comment: My intention is reposition a file after reaching EOF in CL. Please let me know if that is possible using POSDBF. If there is any alternative advise on that as well.

Comment: See Charles answer, to do anything more involved will require something other than CL. If you really want to use a scripting language, you could try Rexx.